# GD_ gets added to path when downloading file using URLSession with BlackBerry Dynamic SDK in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, blackberry, good-dynamics, blackberry-dynamics

I have integrated Blackberry dynamics sdk3.4.1.82 in my iOS Swift application.

I am downloading file from server using "downloadTask" method. Once file get downloaded, "tempLocalUrl" gets added "GD_" in path. But actual in filesystem name doesn't contain "GD_" string. File is stored with name "tmp/CFNetworkDownload_sdfaa.tmp".

Swift's URLSession downloadtask method is:

```
let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
```

How do I access the file  using BB dynamics API?

I  am not able to get file using GD filesystem like :

```
try GDFileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
```